# How can I iterate a list of users and create each user on a machine in Ansible?

Tags: python, ansible

I have a list of users from an external source and a remote machine. I want to take the list from the external source and compare it against my current machine's user list and create users for each user that does not exist on the machine.

I have tried this using ansible runner (pseudo-code below):

```
for user in users: 
  updateUsers(user)
```

which will call an Ansible.runner object and make the following call:

```
ansible.runner.Runner(
  pattern='tools',
  forks=10,
  module_name='user',
  module_args="",
  complex_args=OrderedDict(sorted(dict(name=name, group=group, state=state).items())),
  sudo=True,
).run()
```

For now group and state are defined globally.
My issue is that as this traverses the for-loop, it does indeed create users as I have specified it to do so; the main issue is that it creates users and then the permissions on the home directories of each respective user do not allow the user access to it. So say "joeshmo" was a user: he would not be able to write to his own ~/ dir.

I am looking for some guidance on how I'm doing this.
Is there a way with playbook to dynamically iterate through a file and grab different user names to add them as users to the system without the permission errors?
Is there a way to fix my current script to not have these errors?

Thank you

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you need to do this in code? Because it seems to me you should be able to do this using a playbook with a task that "registers" the user list, and a separate task that uses "with_items" to create all the users. Ansible strives to be idempotent, so multiple calls to create existing users will do nothing .

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use code to get your users list, you can [write your own iterators](http://docs.ansible.com/developing_plugins.html#lookup-plugins) in python and put them in a `lookup_plugins` dir next to your playbook. Then you can do this:

```
    # Use my custom users.py lookup plugin 
    - user: name={{item.name}} group={{item.group}} state=present
      with_users:
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it.

1. Create a [custom facts](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#local-facts-facts-d) script to get all your user/group info from the machine during fact gathering. This file can be any shell executable that output valid JSON
2. Compare the list of fact gathered users/groups with your external source (not sure what format you have it stored in) and add/delete users appropriately.

I know there is a bit of overhead with creating, deploying and managing an additional script for custom facts but I think it's worth it.  I've attempted to gather all sorts of information using just playbook and it can get really ugly and you'll end up writing all sorts of filter plugins, curse the set_fact module and end up with a 200 line playbook.